# Retrieving attributes of objects stored in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
class Customer:
def __init__(self,custid,name,addr,city,state,zipcode):
    self.custid=custid
    self.name=name
    self.addr=addr
    self.city=city
    self.state=state
    self.zipcode=zipcode
    self.memberLevel=BasicMember()
    self.monthlySpending =0
```

Well i am able to read a file and then split it such that in dictionary key is my customerid and value is the customer object. But i can't retrieve the attributes for each object stored in my dictionary. How to get each objects attributes from dictionary.

```
for line in open('customers.dat','r'):
item=line.rstrip(',')
intput =line.split(',')
cc=Customer.Customer(*intput)
s2=item.split(',',1)[0]
d[s2]=[cc]
```

sample data of customer is :

```
619738273,Admiral Ackbar,383 NeiMoidian Road,Utapau,MA,01720
118077058,Padme Amidala,846 Amani Road,D'Qar,MA,01508
360513913,Wedge Antilles,700 NeiMoidian Road,D'Qar,MA,01508
```

while my output after storing each object in dictionary is :

```
{'739118188': [<Customer.Customer object at 0x005FF8B0>], 
'578148567': [<Customer.Customer object at 0x005FF9B0>]}
```

So how to get attributes for the object stored in the dictionary.

Comment: Same way as any other object. Why are you wrapping the Customer instance in a list, though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you wrapped each one in a list, but simply access them as normal:

```
>>> d['619738273'][0].name
'Admiral Ackbar'
```

I'd recommend not wrapping each one in a list:

```
d[s2] = cc
```

Then you don't need the `[0]`:

```
>>> d['619738273'].name
'Admiral Ackbar'
```

You can also streamline the parsing step:

```
with open('customers.dat') as f:
    for line in f:
        k,*data = line.split(',')
        d[k] = Customer.Customer(k, *data)
```

Although it'd be better to use `csv`, since it looks like you're working with a CSV file:

```
import csv
with open('customers.dat') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for k,*data in reader:
        d[k] = Customer.Customer(k, *data)
```

Comment: actually i have to perform some operations on customer data. so for that once i read from file i need to store in a structure thats why i used dictionary

Comment: thanks it works. is it 2 d array to access the object attributes in dictionary ?

Comment: @Kam - No, it's a simple dictionary with no arrays or lists at all.

Comment: thanks. is there any better way to store objects. as you said so. thanks

Comment: @Kam - If you want to look them up by an ID, a dictionary seems like a fine way to go.